# "ЭThe app has not been configured with a WORKSPACE_ID environment variable" error for app on NodeJS in bluemix

Tags: json, node.js, service, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I want to push the car_dashboard application into bluemix. I downloaded the code from https://conversation-demo.mybluemix.net/ (the simple version) and I connected to bluemix with the CMD (cf login) and then I did this:

```
cf push name_application -p the_path_in_my_pc
```

But when I run the application in bluemix, I have this message:

> """""""The app has not been configured with a WORKSPACE_ID environment variable. Please refer to the README documentation on how to set this variable. 
>   Once a workspace has been defined the intents may be imported from here in order to get a working application."""""

I created a workspace with the car_dashboard JSON and I modified .env and manifest.yml with the WORKSPACE_ID , username and password of the service. then I did the push but I had the same error.

Comment: Can you include a sanitised version of your manifest.yml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an environment variable (VCAP_SERVICES) to the Bluemix app. The variable name should be WORKSPACE_ID and its value should be the workspace id of the workspace you are trying to connect to.